# No file matches include / exclude patterns

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a serverless layer deployment that was working just fine previously.  Now for some reason every time i run a deploy or package I get this error

```
  No file matches include / exclude patterns
```

My serverless.yml hasn't changed at all and didn't include/exclude patterns previously (and I had no issues uploading my layers.

Here ism y folder structure

```
root
|serverless.yml
___chromedriver
|   binary_to_upload_with_layer
|   binary2_to_upload_with_layer
```

And here is my yml that worked fine to upload these binaries as layers

```
#serverless.yml

service: selenium-layer

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: us-east-1
  timeout: 900

  
layers:
  selenium:
    path: selenium
    compatibleRuntimes: [ "python3.6" ]
  chromedriver:
    path: chromedriver
    description: chrome driver layer
    

    compatibleRuntimes: [
      "python3.6"
    ]


resources:

# (arn:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:lambda:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:\d{12}:layer:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+:[0-9]+)| 
  Outputs:
    #arn:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:lambda:::awslayer:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)] arn:seleniumlayeout:lambda:::awslayer:12345
    SeleniumLayerExport:
      Value: 
          Ref: SeleniumLambdaLayer  # supposed tobe camelcase Layer name + LambdaLayer 
      Export:
        Name: SeleniumLambdaLayer
    LambdaExportLayer:
      Value: 
        Ref: ChromedriverLambdaLayer

      Export:
        Name: ChromedriverLambdaLayer
```

I have tried adding the include patterns based on the serverless docs

```
package:
  patterns:
    - '!test_folder/**'
    - 'chromedriver/**'
```

but get the same error.

Any ideas here on 1. what changed since it worked before and 2.  what can I do to resolve this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i resolved this one guys.

I had an extra layer configured who's path had no files in it...

```
root
|serverless.yml
___chromedriver
|   binary_to_upload_with_layer
|   binary2_to_upload_with_layer
__emptylayerfolder
|  .
|  ..
```

By removing the 'emptylayerfolder' (or adding any files to it)  I was able to resolve this error message.